# Android SQLite database doesnot Update and Delete

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, sql-delete

This is mainactivity which provides the user Input

```
public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity{
private DBMANAGER_person dbmanager_person;
private ListView listView;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

final String [] from = new String[]{MyDB.COLUMN_ID, MyDB.COLUMN_NAME, MyDB.COLUMN_AGE, MyDB.COLUMN_HEIGHT , MyDB.COLUMN_WEIGHT};
final int [] to = new int[]{R.id.nameTV,R.id.ageTV,R.id.heightTV,R.id.weightTV};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    dbmanager_person = new DBMANAGER_person(this);
    dbmanager_person.open();

    Cursor cursor = dbmanager_person.fetch();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyTV));

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.person, cursor, from, to,0);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView idTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.idTV);
            TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
            TextView ageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ageTV);
            TextView heightTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heightTV);
            TextView weightTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.weightTV);

            String iD = idTextView.getText().toString();
            String name = nameTextView.getText().toString();
            String age = ageTextView.getText().toString();
            String height = heightTextView.getText().toString();
            String weight = weightTextView.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Modiffy_person_Details.class);
            intent.putExtra("_id",iD);
            intent.putExtra("name", name);
            intent.putExtra("age", age);
            intent.putExtra("height", height);
            intent.putExtra("weight", weight);

            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_person,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.add){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Add_people.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }else if (id == R.id.logout){
        Intent backToHome = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(backToHome);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

This is Add_prople class

public class Add_people extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText nameEditText;
    private EditText ageEditText;
    private EditText heightEditText;
    private EditText weightEditText;

```
private Button save;
private DBMANAGER_person dbmanager_person;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTitle("Add People");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_people);

    nameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameET);
    ageEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ageET);
    heightEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightET);
    weightEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightET);

    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);

    dbmanager_person = new DBMANAGER_person(this);
    dbmanager_person.open();
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.saveBtn:
            final String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
            final String age = ageEditText.getText().toString();
            final String height = heightEditText.getText().toString();
            final String weight = weightEditText.getText().toString();

            dbmanager_person.insert(name,age,height,weight);

            Intent main = new Intent(this,Welcome.class)
                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(main);
            break;

    }

}
```

}

This is DBMANAGER_person class where the CRUD operation works

This is the Modiffy_person_Details class where user can Update and Delete their information

```
public class DBMANAGER_person {
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private MyDB myDB;
private Context context;

public DBMANAGER_person(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public DBMANAGER_person open() throws SQLiteException{
    myDB = new MyDB(context);
    database = myDB.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    myDB.close();
}
public void insert(String name,String age,String height,String weight){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MyDB.COLUMN_NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(MyDB.COLUMN_AGE,age);
    contentValues.put(MyDB.COLUMN_HEIGHT,height);
    contentValues.put(MyDB.COLUMN_WEIGHT,weight);
    database.insert(MyDB.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
}

public Cursor fetch(){
    String[] columns  = new String[]{MyDB.COLUMN_ID, MyDB.COLUMN_NAME, MyDB.COLUMN_AGE , MyDB.COLUMN_HEIGHT, MyDB.COLUMN_WEIGHT};
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery( "select rowid _id,* from "+MyDB.TABLE_NAME, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor;
}

public int update(long id, String name, String age, String height, String weight){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MyDB.COLUMN_NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(MyDB.COLUMN_AGE,age);
    contentValues.put(MyDB.COLUMN_HEIGHT,height);
    contentValues.put(MyDB.COLUMN_WEIGHT,weight);
    int i = database.update(MyDB.TABLE_NAME,contentValues,MyDB.COLUMN_ID + " = "+id,null);
    return i;
}

public void delete(long id){
    database.delete(MyDB.TABLE_NAME, MyDB.COLUMN_ID + "="+ id,null);
}
```

}

public class Modiffy_person_Details extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private EditText nameField;
    private EditText ageField;
    private EditText heightField;
    private EditText weightField;

```
private Button update;
private Button delete;

private long _id;
private DBMANAGER_person dbmanager_person;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("Modify Record");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_modiffy_person__details);

    dbmanager_person = new DBMANAGER_person(this);
    dbmanager_person.open();

    nameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    ageField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ageEditText);
    heightField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightEditText);
    weightField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightEditText);

    update = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update_btn);
    delete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String ID = intent.getStringExtra("_id");
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    String age = intent.getStringExtra("age");
    String height = intent.getStringExtra("height");
    String weight = intent.getStringExtra("weight");

    String check_ID = ID;
    if(!check_ID.equals("")) {

        _id = Long.parseLong(ID);
    }/*else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There is no id",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }*/



        nameField.setText(name);
        ageField.setText(age);
        heightField.setText(height);
        weightField.setText(weight);





    update.setOnClickListener(this);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.update_btn:
            String na = nameField.getText().toString();
            String ag = ageField.getText().toString();
            String hei = heightField.getText().toString();
            String wei = weightField.getText().toString();

            dbmanager_person.update( _id , na , ag,hei,wei);
            this.returnHome();
            break;
        case R.id.delete_btn:
            dbmanager_person.delete(_id);
            this.returnHome();
            break;
    }

}

public void returnHome(){
    Intent home_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(home_intent);
}
```

}

My problem is whenever i want to update or delete my information it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the returned values for both delete and update. For both functions, it returns 0 for no rows affected, or it returns 1 if there are rows are affected. If it's 0, then your issue is dealing with the SQL query itself, in which case the first thing to check would be the validity of the IDs.

[`update`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

[`delete`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))